# After creating an In App Purchase what is the process for the player to choose between the purchases

Tags: ios, xcode, in-app-purchase, menuitem

Say in a game I created an In App Purchase for the players to buy more characters and backgrounds. What would I have to do in order to give the player the option of switching back and forth between them. 
If there are any good references or tutorials I would appreciate it.

Also how difficult is that to incorporate? Essentially there would be a button that would pull up a page. From there you check/press the purchase you already have or want to buy and then it'll switch to using that item.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is basically seperate from the process of in-app purchases, but simply UI design.

Once a user has purchased an unlockable (or restored it from a previous purchase), you can keep track of his purchases in your own database, or in the UserDefaults dictionary.

Next, in your UI for switching between characters and backgrounds, you can show a list of all possible characters/backgrounds, and only enable those that have ther ID in the userdefaults' array of unlocked items.